# How *.dsc files are related to *.deb and source code files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation, package, debian

Without packaging system we have (A) source code, which can be translated/compiled to (B) binary code.

In case of debian/ubuntu packages we have (1) source code, (2) source package - **dsc** file and (3) binary package - **deb** file. How is it that (2) source package related to (1) and (3)? Why do we need it? And, the most important question: what is the workflow generating (2) and (3) from (1)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The workflow usually goes approximately like this:

1. Someone not affiliated with Debian writes some source code and posts it as a package on the web, for example, [splint-3.1.2.tar.gz](http://www.splint.org/downloads/splint-3.1.2.src.tgz)
2. Someone at Debian downloads the source code, and writes

   1. A set of patch files to make the source build on Debian and conform to Debian guidelines. Run

      ```
      curl -s 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/splint/splint_3.1.2.dfsg1-2.diff.gz' | gunzip -dc | less
      ```

      to see this for the example package.
   2. A [textual metadata file](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/splint/splint_3.1.2.dfsg1-2.dsc) describing the package—this is the `.dsc` file and `debian/control` file. “DSC” is an acronym for Debian Source Control.
3. Binary `.deb` packages are built for each architecture from the original upstream source code with the Debian-specific patches applied. [Here is one such file](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/splint/splint_3.1.2.dfsg1-2_amd64.deb). The [Debian Binary Package Building HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/) explains the format of these files and how to inspect them.

The `.dsc` file is not used for build logic, it is more for metadata. However many tools along the way require it. For example, the `Build-Depends:` field is used to install required build dependencies.

Comment: Great answer! One more question. In example you gave here, we have original code (upstream) and diff after maintainer changes. When new version of original code is about to be "debianized" how maintainers keep track on theirs changes? They merging diff from previous deb release to new version of source code? Do they used some CVS?

Comment: After a new release, they'll generally just re-apply the patches in the old `.diff.gz.` If something breaks they will go digging. Some maintainers may use `git` or `quilt` or other tools I don’t know about, but as far as I know, it's really up to the package maintainer.

Comment: Some of the links in your answer are broken.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually much more complicated than that. The idea behind Debian packages is that they contain all the information needed to buld a page. Usually, the source is modified to include a `debian` directory that includes a `control` file describing the dependencies of that package and other packages that it interacts with (e.g, breaks, replaces, provides virtual package). A `rules` file explains how to build and install the package. There are also descriptions of how to package since a single source package can become many binary packages (e.g., `foo-utils`, `libfoo0`, `libfoo-dev`). `debuild` actually reads this information, does the compilation, and produces the binary packages. A subtlety: if `foo` uses `libbar-dev`, I may not actually know/care what version of the `libbar` binary package I use. `pbuilder` runs `debuild` in a clean environment so there is no chance of compiling against things you have not explicitly specified.

Consult the [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) for details.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So far I've used debuild, but you are saying I should use pbuilder instead? What are source packages? They are not used? Link you post it is great, but size of it scared me from reading :)

Comment: pbuilder is a convenience tool for verifying that the dependencies are fully specified. It basically creates a virtual environment with nothing except the declared dependencies; if it cannot complete the build, it often means you have an undeclared dependency. But if you are just interested in producing a `.deb` file here and now, it's not necessary to have this strictness.

Comment: A source package is the debianized source, i.e. basically the .orig.tar.gz plus your debdiffs. This is what you need to provide to others who want to create your .deb file for themselves, perhaps with their own patches or tweaks, or perhaps they want to build the package for a different architecture. If you want to provide this to others, `pbuilder` may start to make sense.